# getting error while Deleting checked rows using apex in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am deleting rows based on checkbox click.But when i select a checkbox and click delete , i am displayed this error " DML statement found null SObject at position 0
Error is in expression '{!del}' in component  in page forecastbywarehouse: Class.ForecastByWarehouseController.del: line 269, column 1"

Could you please help me in this.

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="ForecastByWarehouseController" title="Forecast By Warehouse">

    <script>
        var elementFocus = null;
        function retainFocus()
        {
            document.getElementById(elementFocus.name).focus();
        }

        function JS_QtyChanged(ele)
        {
            console.log(ele);
            console.log(ele.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes);
            var sum = 0;
            var i;
            var nodes=ele.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes;
            for(i in ele.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes)
            {
                console.log(nodes[i].className);
                if(nodes[i].className == "quantityTableCell"){
                    var className = nodes[i].childNodes[0].className;
                    if((className=="quantityCellRed" || className=="quantityCell"))
                    {
                        var val = nodes[i].childNodes[0].value;
                        console.log(val);
                        if(!isNaN(val) && val !='undefined' && val != null && val != '')
                        {
                            //alert(val);
                            sum += parseFloat(val);
                        }

                    }                   
                }


                if(nodes[i].className == "quantityTotalCell"){
                    oldvalue = parseInt(nodes[i].innerHTML);
                    if(oldvalue != sum){
                        ele.className = "quantityCellRed";
                    }
                    var n = sum.toFixed(2);
                    nodes[i].innerHTML = n;
                }
            }
            //call_qtyChanged();
        }
    </script>
    <apex:form id="frm">
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" title="Select Warehouse">
                <apex:inputField value="{!objProdInventory.gii__Warehouse__c}" label="Warehouse"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!objForecast.Sales_Year__c}" label="Sales Year"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!fetchProducts}" rerender="frm"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:pageblock id="pb_filter" rendered="{!warehouseSelected }">
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" title="Filter Products">
                <apex:selectList size="1" label="Search By" value="{!strFilterBy}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!filterBy}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:inputText value="{!searchText}" label="Search Text"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchProducts}" rerender="pb_products"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
        <apex:outputpanel id="pb_products" >
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!IF(lstProdWrapper.size>0,true,false)}">            
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!del}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save & Exit" action="{!saveNexit}"/>                

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <center>
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="pSearchShowMore" id="otpNav">

                    <apex:image url="/img/search_prevarrow_disabled.gif" styleClass="prevArrow" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasPrevious)}"/>
                    <apex:image url="/img/search_prevarrow.gif" title="Previous Page" styleClass="prevArrow" rendered="{!Con.HasPrevious}"/>
                    <apex:commandLink action="{!Previous}" title="Previous Page" value="Previous Page" rendered="{!HasPrevious}" reRender="pb_products"/>
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(HasPrevious)}">Previous Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                    &nbsp;({!IF(PageNumber == 0,1,(PageNumber * PageSize)+1)}-{!IF(CountTotalRecords != null && CountTotalRecords < PageSize,CountTotalRecords,((PageNumber+1) * PageSize))})&nbsp;
                    <apex:outputPanel styleClass="pShowLess noLink" style="color:grey" rendered="{!NOT(HasNext)}" >Next Page</apex:outputPanel>         
                    <apex:commandLink title="Next Page" value="Next Page" rendered="{!HasNext}" action="{!Next}" reRender="pb_products"/>&nbsp;
                    <apex:image url="/img/search_nextarrow.gif" title="Next Page" styleClass="nextArrow" rendered="{!Con.HasNext}"/>
                    <apex:image url="/img/search_nextarrow_disabled.gif" rendered="{!NOT(Con.HasNext)}"/>          
                </apex:outputPanel>
            </center><br/>

            <apex:outputpanel id="tablevalues" >
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>{!$Label.Action}</th>                    
                    <th>{!$Label.Forecast_Product_Code}</th>
                    <th>{!$Label.Forecast_Product_SKU}</th>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!allMonths}" var="month">
                        <th align="center">{!month}</th>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    <th>{!$Label.Forecast_Total}</th>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!lstProdWrapper}" var="prod">
                    <tr>
                        <td><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!prod.checked}"/></td>                        
                        <td width="140px">{!prod.productSKU}</td>
                        <td width="80px">{!prod.productCode}</td>
                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="count"/>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!allMonths}" var="mon">
                            <td class="quantityTableCell">
                                <apex:inputText value="{!prod.monthQty[mon]}" styleClass="{!if(prod.cellEdited[mon],'quantityCellRed','quantityCell')}" onchange="JS_QtyChanged(this)"/>                                
                            </td>
                        </apex:repeat>
                        <td align="right" padding-top= "2px" class="quantityTotalCell">
                            <b><apex:outputText value="{!prod.total}"/></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </table> 
            </apex:outputpanel>           
        </apex:pageBlock>       
        <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!IF(lstProdWrapper.size==0 && warehouseSelected ,true,false)}">
            <apex:pageBlock >
                {!$Label.No_Result_Found}
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My apex class

```
global class ForecastByWarehouseController
{
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController con{get; set;}
    public List<gii__ProductInventory__c> lstProdInventory{get;set;}
    public gii__ProductInventory__c objProdInventory{get;set;}
    public gii__Warehouse__c objWarehouse{get;set;}
    public Forecast__c objForecast{get;set;}
    public String Searchtext{get;set;}
    public List<ProductWrapper> lstProdWrapper{get;set;}
    public String strFilterBy{get;set;}
    public boolean noResultFound {get;set;}
    public boolean warehouseSelected {get;set;}
    public Integer CountTotalRecords{get;set;}
    public Integer NoOfPages{get;set;}
    public Integer PageSize{get;set;}
    public Integer PageNumber{get;set;}
    public String soql;
    public List<Forecast__c> allForecast;
    public gii__Warehouse__c selectedWarehouse;
    public Sales_Year__c selectSalesYear;
    public List<String> allMonths{get;set;}
    public String filterQueryPart;

    public ForecastByWarehouseController()
    {
        Searchtext = '';
        strFilterBy = '';
        objProdInventory = new gii__ProductInventory__c();
        lstProdInventory = new List<gii__ProductInventory__c>();
        objForecast = new Forecast__c();
        lstProdWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();
        PageSize = 10;
        PageNumber = 0;
        warehouseSelected = false;
        allMonths = new List<String>{'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October', 'November','December'};
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getFilterBy() 
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('All','All Products'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('gii__Family__c','Product Family'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('gii__Color__r.name','Color'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('gii__ProductStyle__r.name','Style'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('gii__Size__c','Size'));
        return options;
    }

    public void addFilters()
    {
        system.debug('\n--strFilterBy--'+strFilterBy+'\n--Constants.STYLEFILTER--'+Constants.STYLEFILTER);        
        if((strFilterBy != '' && searchText != '')&& (strFilterBy != 'All')  && ((strFilterBy == Constants.STYLEFILTER) || (strFilterBy == Constants.COLORFILTER) || (strFilterBy == Constants.FAMILYFILTER) ))
        {
            filterQueryPart = ' AND gii__Product__r.' + strFilterBy + ' LIKE \'%' + searchText + '%\'';
        }
        else if((strFilterBy != '' && searchText != '') && (strFilterBy == 'All') )
        {
            filterQueryPart = ' AND gii__Product__r.Name LIKE \'%' + searchText + '%\'';
        }
        else
            filterQueryPart = '';
        system.debug('\n--filterQueryPart--'+filterQueryPart);
    }

    public PageReference searchProducts() 
    {
        fetchProducts();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference fetchProducts() 
    {
        PageSize = 10;
        PageNumber = 0;
        warehouseSelected = true;
        selectedWarehouse = [select id,name from gii__Warehouse__c where id=:objProdInventory.gii__Warehouse__c];
        selectSalesYear = [select id,name from Sales_Year__c where id=:objForecast.Sales_Year__c];
        createWrapper();
        return null;
    }

    public void createWrapper()
    {
        lstProdWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();        
        addFilters();
        system.debug('\n--searchText--'+searchText);
        soql = 'Select id,gii__Product__r.gii__ProductStyle__r.name,name,gii__Product__c,gii__Product__r.name,gii__Product__r.gii__ProductCode__c,gii__Warehouse__c from gii__ProductInventory__c where gii__Product__r.gii__Style__c <> true AND gii__Warehouse__c =\'' + selectedWarehouse.id + '\' ' + filterQueryPart  + ' Order By gii__Product__r.gii__ProductStyle__r.name NULLS LAST,gii__Product__r.name limit ' + PageSize + ' offset ' + PageNumber*PageSize;
        String soql4count = 'Select count() from gii__ProductInventory__c where gii__Warehouse__c =\'' + selectedWarehouse.id + '\'';
        CountTotalRecords= Database.countQuery(soql4count);
        NoOfPages = CountTotalRecords/PageSize;
        if(NoOfPages * PageSize < CountTotalRecords)
            NoOfPages++;
        System.debug(soql);
        lstProdInventory = Database.query(soql);
        allForecast = [select id,Product_Inventory__c,Sales_Year__c, (select id,name,Quantity__c,Month__c from Forecast_Details__r) from Forecast__c where Product_Inventory__c IN: lstProdInventory and Sales_Year__c =: selectSalesYear.id ];
        Decimal totalForecast = 0;
        for(gii__ProductInventory__c pi : lstProdInventory)
        {
            ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper();
            pw.productstyle = pi.gii__Product__r.gii__ProductStyle__r.name;
            pw.monthQty = new Map<String,String>();
            pw.oldMonthQty = new Map<String,String>();
            pw.idMonthQty = new Map<String,String>();
            pw.cellEdited = new Map<String,Boolean>();
            pw.productSKU = pi.gii__Product__r.name;
            pw.productCode = pi.gii__Product__r.gii__ProductCode__c;
            pw.ProForecast = createForecast(pi,selectSalesYear);
            totalForecast = 0;
            for(Forecast_Detail__c fd :  pw.ProForecast.Forecast_Details__r)
            {
                pw.monthQty.put(fd.Month__c,String.valueOf(fd.Quantity__c));
                pw.oldMonthQty.put(fd.Month__c,String.valueOf(fd.Quantity__c));
                pw.IdMonthQty.put(fd.Month__c,fd.id);
                system.debug('\n--fd.Quantity__c;--'+fd.Quantity__c);
                totalForecast += fd.Quantity__c;
            }
            pw.total = String.valueOf(totalForecast);
            system.debug('\n--pw.total--'+pw.total);
            for(integer i=0;i<12;i++)
            {
                if(!pw.monthQty.keyset().contains(allMonths[i]))
                {
                    pw.monthQty.put(allMonths[i],'');
                    pw.oldMonthQty.put(allMonths[i],'xxx');
                }
                pw.cellEdited.put(allMonths[i],false);
            }
            system.debug('\n--pw.total--'+pw.total);
            system.debug('\n--SIZEFILTER --'+Constants.SIZEFILTER );
            // case when user do filter by size 
            if(strFilterBy == Constants.SIZEFILTER )
            {
                if(!string.isEmpty(Searchtext))
                {
                    if(Integer.valueOf(Searchtext) == Integer.valueOf(pw.total))
                    {
                        lstProdWrapper.add(pw);
                    }               
                }
                else
                {
                    lstProdWrapper.add(pw);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                lstProdWrapper.add(pw);
            }
        }
        lstProdWrapper.sort();
    }

    public Forecast__c createForecast(gii__ProductInventory__c proInv, Sales_Year__c  syear)
    {
        for(Forecast__c f : allForecast)
        {
            if(f.Product_Inventory__c == proInv.id && f.Sales_Year__c == syear.id)
            return f;
        }
        Forecast__c fore = new Forecast__c();
        fore.name = proInv.gii__Product__r.name + '-' + proInv.name + '-' + syear.name;
        fore.Product_Inventory__c = proInv.id;
        fore.Sales_Year__c = syear.id;
        fore.Warehouse__c = proInv.gii__Warehouse__c;
        fore.Product_Reference__c = proInv.gii__Product__c;
        insert fore;
        return fore;
    }

    public PageReference save() 
    {
        List<Forecast_Detail__c> lstChild = new List<Forecast_Detail__c>();
        for(ProductWrapper objProdWrap : lstProdWrapper)
        {
            for(integer i=0;i<12;i++)
            {
                if(objProdWrap.monthQty.get(allMonths[i]) != null && objProdWrap.monthQty.get(allMonths[i]) != '')
                {
                    if(objProdWrap.oldMonthQty.get(allMonths[i]) == 'xxx')
                    {
                        lstChild.add(new Forecast_Detail__c(name=allMonths[i]+'-'+selectSalesYear.name, Month__c=allMonths[i], Quantity__c=Decimal.valueOf(objProdWrap.monthQty.get(allMonths[i])), Forecast__c=objProdWrap.ProForecast.id));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lstChild.add(new Forecast_Detail__c(id=objProdWrap.IdMonthQty.get(allMonths[i]),name=allMonths[i]+'-'+selectSalesYear.name, Month__c=allMonths[i], Quantity__c=Decimal.valueOf(objProdWrap.monthQty.get(allMonths[i])), Forecast__c=objProdWrap.ProForecast.id));
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
        upsert lstChild;
        createWrapper();
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference saveNexit() 
    {
        save();
        PageReference pref = new PageReference(Label.Forecast_RetURL);
        return pref;
    }

    global class ProductWrapper implements Comparable
    {
        public string productstyle {get;set;}
        public String productSKU{get;set;}
        public String productCode{get;set;}
        public Forecast__c ProForecast{get;set;}
        public String total{get;set;}
        public Map<String, String> monthQty{get;set;}
        public Map<String, String> oldMonthQty{get;set;}
        public Map<String, Id> IdMonthQty{get;set;}
        public Map<String, Boolean> cellEdited{get;set;}
        public Boolean checked {get;set;}
        public gii__ProductInventory__c emp {get;set;}

        global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
            ProductWrapper compareToEmp = (ProductWrapper)compareTo;
            if (productstyle == compareToEmp.productstyle) return 0;
            if (productstyle > compareToEmp.productstyle) return 1;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public Boolean hasNext
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageNumber+1)<NoOfPages;
        }
        set;
    }

    public Boolean hasPrevious
    {
        get
        {
            return PageNumber>0;
        }
        set;
    }


    public void previous()
    {
        PageNumber--;
        createWrapper();
    }

    public void next()
    {
        PageNumber++;
        createWrapper();
    }    

    public void del() {
        List<gii__ProductInventory__c> listEmpForDel = new List<gii__ProductInventory__c>();
        List<ProductWrapper> listTempWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();
        for(ProductWrapper w : lstProdWrapper) {
            if(w.checked) {
                listEmpForDel.add(w.emp);
            } else {
                listTempWrapper.add(w);
            }
        }
        System.debug('++++++++++++Size++++++++++++++++++ :'+listEmpForDel.size());
        System.debug('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'+listTempWrapper+'\n');
        if(listEmpForDel.size() > 0) {
            delete listEmpForDel;
            lstProdWrapper= listTempWrapper;
        } else {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Select atleast one Account to delete'));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says that your list contains ***null*** record at position 0.

You cannot delete ***null***.

I believe if you add additional check if you have wrappers around ***null*** object it should work fine.

Check this:

```
public void del() {
    List<gii__ProductInventory__c> listEmpForDel = new     List<gii__ProductInventory__c>();
    List<ProductWrapper> listTempWrapper = new List<ProductWrapper>();
    for(ProductWrapper w : lstProdWrapper) {
        if(w.checked) {
            if ( w.emp != null )
               listEmpForDel.add(w.emp);
        } else {
            listTempWrapper.add(w);
        }
    }
    System.debug('++++++++++++Size++++++++++++++++++ :'+listEmpForDel.size());
    System.debug('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'+listTempWrapper+'\n');
    if(listEmpForDel.size() > 0) {
        delete listEmpForDel;
        lstProdWrapper= listTempWrapper;
    } else {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Select atleast one Account to delete'));
    }
}
```

### ======================================

Update:

the reason why emp is null is because you never populate it.

This is like in the matrix: why do my eyes hurt - because you've never used them. [image: why do my eyes hurt - matrix]
[image: why do my eyes hurt - matrix] 
^_^ :)

Please consider adding line

```
pw.emp = pi;
```

to your createWrapper method overthere

```
for(gii__ProductInventory__c pi : lstProdInventory)
    {
        ProductWrapper pw = new ProductWrapper();
        pw.emp = pi;
        pw.productstyle = pi.gii__Product__r.gii__ProductStyle__r.name;
        pw.monthQty = new Map<String,String>();
```

Comment: thanks for help..but even if i am selecting the checkboxes ..nothing is deleting

Comment: i dont know why the records related to checked checkbox are coming as null

Comment: Do you populate anywhere emp? If you never populate it then it will be always null. I think I understand what is wrong with your code

Comment: by the way, does emp stand for Electromagnetic pulse from Matrix? matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Electromagnetic_pulse

Comment: i guess i am not populating it anywhere..but how can i link the checkbox to the record that i am showing ob VF page??

Comment: I have updated my answer: please trying adding line pw.emp = pi;

Comment: Patlatus -- forum etiquette is to avoid using graphic memes and the like